# Sheafified version of the Čech complex.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $\frak{U}$ be an open cover of topological space $X$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $X$.

Hartshorne's book said that

> For any open subset $V\subset X$, let $f:V\to X$ be the inclusion map. We construct a complex $\mathcal{C}(U,\mathcal{F})$ (not $C(U,\mathcal{F})$) of sheaves on $X$ as follows. For each $p \geq 0$ let
>
> $\mathcal{C}^p(U,\mathcal{F}) := \Pi_{i_0<i_1<...<i_p}
>  f_*\mathcal{F}|_{U_{i_0,i_1,...,i_p}}$
>
> and define $d:\mathcal{C}^{p}\to \mathcal{C}^{p-1}$ by the same formula as above. Note by construction that for each $p$ we have
>
> $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{C}^p(U,\mathcal{F}))=C^p(U,\mathcal{F}).$

I am not sure this definition.

I think $\mathcal{C}^p(U,\mathcal{F})$ is a sheaf $\mathcal{S}$ such that

$\mathcal{S}(V)=\Pi_{i_0<i_1<...<i_p}\mathcal{F}(U_{i_0,i_1,...,i_p}\cap V)$

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's the only interpretation which makes sense of the stuff on the following page.